# Am I using histc wrong, or is this MATLAB's fault?

Tags: matlab, histogram, bins

Ok, here's some code in MATLAB:

```
data = [1 1.5 2 3 4 4.5 5 6 7 7 7 0 0 0];

histc(data, [1:1:5])
histc(data, [1:1:5, inf])
histc(data, [-inf, 1:1:5])
```

which outputs the following:

```
ans = 2     1     1     2     1
ans = 2     1     1     2     5     0
ans = 3     2     1     1     2     1
```

My question is, why does MATLAB return a useless 0 when you use inf in the bin size (to mean >= 5 in this case)?

Won't it always be zero?  The help says the output will always be the same length as the bin size, but isn't that a bad spec in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's actually the correct behavior of [HISTC](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/histc.html). When you use the syntax:

```
n = histc(x,edges);
```

then, from the documentation:

> n(k) counts the value x(i) if edges(k)
>   <= x(i) < edges(k+1). The last bin
>   counts any values of x that match
>   edges(end).

Therefore, the last edge value you give returns the count of how many things *exactly* match it. When **inf** is the last edge value, that counts 0 (i.e. there are no **inf**s in the data). When 5 is the last edge value, it exactly matches 1 value in the data.